# Its possible to POST a form with AJAX to java servlet and redirect?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I explain my problem:

I have one JSP webpage and I have one AJAX call that send some data to one servlet.

The servlet that receive the data have to send this data and more other information to an external URL. This external URL have to be load in the screen with the POST params sent.

Its possible to do this with AJAX and JAVA?

I know that the easy way is send a normal FORM from MYPAGE to this external website (without the servlet) and the form automatic redirects to this external URL, but I dont have all the data, so I need one intermediate servlet to get it...

The schema:

MYPAGE -- (AJAX request to one servlet)---> MY SERVLET ---(POST to an URL with params)---> EXTERNALWEBSITE

The user have to see in the screen the EXTERNALWEBSITE like if the call would be direct between MYPAGE and the EXTERNALWEBSITE

Comment: Yes it's possible, have you given it a try?

Comment: I dont know how do it!!

Comment: Give this a try, it will at least help you create a more specific question: [jQuery AJAX Servlet JSP Web Application Integration Example Tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/4742/jquery-ajax-servlet-jsp-web-application-integration-example-tutorial)

Comment: If you must POST to external website, then you can't use a redirect. I don't think AJAX will help you either. I think your flow should be  MYPAGE ---> MY SERVLET ---(POST to an URL with params)---> EXTERNALWEBSITE ----> return response from external website within MyServlet response.  The only problem with that solution is that the browser's address bar will still point to MyServlet. If you want to try to use that idea, then I could post code.

Comment: In light of @David Levesque answer, I must say I was wrong. AJAX could help you.  You could use either his solution or mine.

Answer (score 0):

You could send the additional data that you need in the response of your Ajax call. Then on the client-side, right after your Ajax call, you can do a `jQuery.post()` to the external URL that will include all the data.